# how to access /data/data/[package] in KitKat (going forward)?

Tags: android

On my Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.2, I've saved some debug data using

```
        fOut = mActivity.openFileOutput("debugdata.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND|Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);  
        osw.write(javaScript+"\n\n");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
```

and, when I go to DDMS -> File Explorer, I am unable to enter the "data" folder.

What is the "new" way to save and access debug data (or any data) to/from a file these days ?

Comment: Irrespective of the permissions of the files inside (which should still work), the data folder itself is not (and has as far as I know has never been) *browsable* on a secured device.  You should still be able to adb pull the actual file from the command line if it has the world read permission.  Or you can use the run-as tool on a debug apk, run on an emulator which is unsecured, have your program save the data on the external storage, etc...

Comment: Great, thanks! I've worked with some (unsecured) devices and had access - I didn't realize it's normally secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I go to DDMS -> File Explorer, I am unable to enter the "data" folder

You have never been able to access that folder, on any production Android device, with the exception of those that you have rooted and specially configured to have access to it. This is nothing new to Android 4.4.

> What is the "new" way to save and access debug data (or any data) to/from a file these days ?

Use an emulator.

Or, use **`adb run-as`** to execute a command (e.g., `cp`) as the user ID associated with your app.

Or, change your code to write to external storage.

Or, add some sort of "export" or "backup" option in your app to copy the file to external storage.

Or, add some sort of "share" option to your app that fires off `ACTION_SEND` to allow you to share the file from the device using your preferred mechanism.

Or, log this to LogCat.

Or, add a log file viewer to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Root your device and change permission

Adb shell (device) -> su - > chmod 777 /data/data/yourpackage

Comment: In addition to being unwise, this isn't as trivial as you seem to think, so this answer is rather incomplete.

Comment: I agree. I think the complete command is `chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.package /data/data/com.application.package/*` but the phone has to be rooted first

Comment: No, do not use 777 - giving others write access to the app's private directory is bad practice.  And you really should give read access to specific files, not the directory.  For that, you don't even need root - you can have the application itself set the file mode.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : i total agree but some one want to complete answer, thank you